# How to have the parent app actively run in background (but not open the app) ios Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, widget

I have today widget in Xamarin , which displays shared data from parent app. Everything works well and widget updates its data until I swipe(kill) parent app.
Is there any way to wake up parent app without opening it, only to get updated data from API?

Comment: Xamarin has some great guides that provides the different ways that iOS supports backgrounding :    https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Service or IntentService in Android. The concept does not exist in iOS, no long running tasks in iOS, in iOS you can use push notifications to wakeup the application.

Comment: As I understood, push notifications can't wake up the app if it was terminated by user.

Comment: There is a way to wakeup iOS application using Notifications see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35388109/523026 hope this helps