# Is there any way so that iOS awake the iOS application after periodic intervals so as to do some small task and sleep again after finishing that task

Tags: ios, process, bluetooth, background, operating-system

I am trying to awake application which is in background/suspended state, after periodic intervals so as to perform small task and sleep again after finishing the task.
I have only seen few scenarios:
1. Audio
2. Location updated
3. Bluetooth communication(Can iOS start the communication with other device)
4. Notification(Can iOS notify the app so as to awake it after periodic interval?)
Is there any other way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388086/is-the-a-way-to-wakeup-suspended-app-in-ios-without-user-or-server-intervention might answer your question

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html link to the documentation and guide

Comment: Another way is through HealthKit Observer